# Dividir string con split cada 3 caracteres

Tags: php

Estoy intentando dividir un número de teléfono cada 3 caracteres con [str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-split.php) de la siguiente forma con PHP:

```
$telefono = "600700800";
$telefono = str_split($telefono, 3);
echo $telefono;
```

Pero el resultado del `echo` me devuelve `Array`.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega cual seria el resultado que esperas obtener

Comment: Lo que te devuelve la función `str_split()` es un `array`. Prueba a hacerle un `print_r()` en vez de un `echo` y ahí verás tus números divididos en grupos de 3 dígitos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El resultado que devuelve la función `str_split` es un array, lo compruebas haciendo esto:

```
echo gettype($telefono);
```

Que imprime:

> array

Entonces para mostrar el resultado puedes hacer lo siguiente indicando entre corchetes el índice o posición que deseas obtener:

```
<?php

$telefono = "600700800";
$telefono = str_split($telefono, 3);


echo $telefono[0]; //devolverá 600

echo $telefono[1]; //devolverá 700

echo $telefono[2]; //devolverá 800
```

O mediante un bucle, por ejemplo un `foreach` así:

```
foreach($telefono as $value){
    echo $value."<br/>";
}
```

Da este resultado:

```
600
700
800
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias! Una observación, por si se necesita particionar una cadena, es mejor usar `mb_str_split()`, ya que éste es más específica con los bytes.